# Create a regular expression to match big numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I get a response from the backend as text in which I have to find a match for numbers which is minimum 16 digits in length.

Let's say I have data something like this:

```text
{"BIG_INT": 123456789012345675,"BIG_INT_ARRAY_SINGLE": [123456789012345676],"BIG_INT_ARRAY_MULTIPLE": [123456789012345661,12345678901234562,12345678901234563,12345678901234564],"STRING_BIG_INT_ARRAY": "[12345678901234567,12345678901234567, 12345678901234567,12345678901234567]","STRING_BIG_INT":"12345678901234567","BIG_INT_FLOATING_DECIMAL": 12345678901234567.76543210987654321}
```

There are certain conditions where it should not match a number:

1. If the number is enclosed within double quotes:
   `("STRING_BIG_INT":"12345678901234567"`)`
2. If the numbers are within string enclosed array:
   `"STRING_BIG_INT_ARRAY":"[12345678901234567,12345678901234567]"`
3. If the number is fractional:
   `"BIG_INT_FLOATING_DECIMAL":12345678901234567.76543210987654321`

Conditions where it should match a number:

1. If it's an integer `"BIG_INT": 123456789012345675`, here value `123456789012345675` should get matched.
2. If it's inside an array `"BIG_INT_ARRAY_MULTIPLE":[123456789012345678,123456789012345678]` here these two numbers should be matched separately.

I tried this regular expression -> `(:\s*)([\[])?(\d{16,})(\s*)([,\}\]])`

One con in this expression is if we have a array of numbers
`"test":[12345678901234567,1236543858688483444,26531562351351374343]`, here my expression only matches the first number. I wanted to match all the numbers inside the array if the array is not enclosed by double quotes.

After matching all numbers, I have code like this to replace numbers to a BigInteger formate(Ex:"16536235653725645345n") and I extract the value part of it and convert the number to a BigInteger.

```
const bigNumsRegExp = new RegExp(/(:\s*)([\[])?(\d{16,})(\s*)([,\}\]])/g);
`const serializedData = data.replace(bigNumsRegExp, '$1$2"$3n"$4$5');`
```

So I only wanted a regular Expression which match numbers only from `BIG_INT`,`BIG_INT_ARRAY_SINGLE` and `BIG_INT_ARRAY_MULTIPLE`

Any help from anyone is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! What exactly are you trying to achieve here? This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, and probably regex may not be the right tool for this. Have you tried parsing the JSON to an object to directy test the types? Do you have control on how the JSON is generated? (if it's a problem because the numbers are too big for JS, the "n" probably should be added when generating the JSON)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the data is valid JSON, but parsing this in JS it can't handle these large numbers, you'll get `BIG_INT: 123456789012345680` for that first value here  (which has lost precision in the last few digits.)

Comment: Don't make your life harder than it needs to be here, by trying to cram this all into one expression. Write one for each of those three constellations you need to handle here (or perhaps combine BIG_INT_ARRAY_SINGLE and BIG_INT_ARRAY_MULTIPLE into one), and then replace the matches for each one of them separately.

Comment: @CBroe you're right, my bad. I'd still argue that there's a more elegant solution than hacking it around in regex

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if they had any control over where that JSON is coming _from_, then I'd say, put those values into quotes then (and apply `BigInt()` after parsing) - but if they don't, and need to work with this _in_ JavaScript now, there might not be too many other options.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [`JSON.parse` source text access](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-parse-with-source#jsonparse-source-text-access) proposal, currently in stage 3, which foresees a third argument for the reviver callback available to `JSON.parse`. This third argument gives access to the source string for the parsed value (second argument), and makes any regex fiddling unnecessary.

Your use case is the motivation for this proposal.

At the time of writing it is available in Chrome and Edge, but not Firefox yet.

This leads to the following code, which will only create `BigInt` values when this feature is supported:

```
function reviver(key, value, info)  {
    const source = info?.source;
    if (!source 
            || typeof value !== "number"
            || Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER <= value && value <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
            || source.includes(".")
            || source.toLowerCase().includes("e")) {
        return value;
    }
    return BigInt(source);
}

let s = '{"BIG_INT": 123456789012345675,"BIG_INT_ARRAY_SINGLE": [123456789012345676],"BIG_INT_ARRAY_MULTIPLE": [123456789012345661,12345678901234562,12345678901234563,12345678901234564],"STRING_BIG_INT_ARRAY": "[12345678901234567,12345678901234567, 12345678901234567,12345678901234567]","STRING_BIG_INT":"12345678901234567","BIG_INT_FLOATING_DECIMAL": 12345678901234567.76543210987654321}';

const result = JSON.parse(s, reviver);
```

In my browser this assigns to `result` the following object:

```
{
    BIG_INT: 123456789012345675n, 
    BIG_INT_ARRAY_SINGLE: [
        123456789012345675n
    ], 
    BIG_INT_ARRAY_MULTIPLE: [
        123456789012345661n,
        12345678901234562n,
        12345678901234563n,
        12345678901234564n
    ],
    STRING_BIG_INT_ARRAY: "[12345678901234567,12345678901234567, 12345678901234567,12345678901234567]",
    STRING_BIG_INT: "12345678901234567",
    BIG_INT_FLOATING_DECIMAL: 12345678901234568
}
```

Note that the reviver excludes the value for `BIG_INT_FLOATING_DECIMAL` from conversion to `BigInt`, because it has a decimal point in the source. I also included a test for scientific notation (and not produce `BigInt` in that case). You could of course handle those cases differently.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing complicated since JSON has a very limited number of types:

- put what you need to preserve in a capture group (strings and floats, numbers with exponant)
- test if the capture group exists in the replacement arrow function and choose what to return.

Example that put double-quotes around integers (when needed):

```
let source = `{
  "BIG_INT": 123456789012345675,
  "BIG_INT_ARRAY_SINGLE": [123456789012345676],
  "BIG_INT_ARRAY_MULTIPLE": [123456789012345661,12345678901234562,12345678901234563,12345678901234564],
  "STRING_BIG_INT_ARRAY": "[12345678901234567,12345678901234567, 12345678901234567,12345678901234567]",
  "STRING_BIG_INT":"12345678901234567",
  "BIG_INT_FLOATING_DECIMAL": 12345678901234567.76543210987654321
}`;

const pattern = /("[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"|\d+\.\d*(?:e[-+]?\d+)?|\d+(?:e[-+]?\d+))|\d+/gi;

let result = source.replace(pattern, (m, g1) => g1 ? g1: `"${m}"`);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JSON reviver that parses https://tsplay.dev/wXyloN

```
function JsonParseWithBigints(json: string) {
  const g = /\b\d+(\.\d+)?\b/g;
  let matches = s.match(g) ?? []
  return JSON.parse(s, (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
      let s = matches.shift()!
      if (+s !== value) throw new Error(s + '!=' + value)
      if (s === `${value}`) return value;
      if (!s.includes('.')) {
        return BigInt(s)
      }
      let [d, f] = s.split('.')
      return { value: BigInt(d + f), exp: -f.length }
    }
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      for (let k of value.match(g) ?? []) {
        let s = matches.shift()!
        if (s !== k) throw new Error(s + '!=' + value)
      }
    }
    return value
  })
}
```

It parses JSON while replacing the numbers that would lose precision while parsing with their BigInt variant taken from the original string

Here's what it produces for your input:

```
{
  "BIG_INT": 1123456789012345675n,
  "BIG_INT_ARRAY_SINGLE": [
    2123456789012345676n
  ],
  "BIG_INT_ARRAY_MULTIPLE": [
    3123456789012345661n,
    412345678901234562n,
    512345678901234563n,
    612345678901234564n
  ],
  "STRING_BIG_INT_ARRAY": "[712345678901234567,812345678901234567, 912345678901234567,1012345678901234567]",
  "STRING_BIG_INT": "1112345678901234567",
  "BIG_INT_FLOATING_DECIMAL": {
    "value": 121234567890123456776543210987654321n,
    "exp": -17
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but indeed regex is a tricky tool, it will fail for example with numeric keys, which are perfectly valid, for example adding `"123":"test",` to the JSON will lead to a shift between the values and the matches. I suppose other constructs can make this fail

Comment: @Kaddath I deliberately ignored those. If one needs, it's straightforward how to add limitations to regex

Comment: yes, this was more a disclaimer for future people reading your answer than a request to update your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *match pattern*.

```
(?<=\"BIG_INT(?:_ARRAY_(?:SINGLE|MULTIPLE))?\":\s\[?)\d{16,}(?:,\d{16,})*
```

Here is an example.

```js
s = '{"BIG_INT": 123456789012345675,"BIG_INT_ARRAY_SINGLE": [123456789012345676],"BIG_INT_ARRAY_MULTIPLE": [123456789012345661,12345678901234562,12345678901234563,12345678901234564],"STRING_BIG_INT_ARRAY": "[12345678901234567,12345678901234567, 12345678901234567,12345678901234567]","STRING_BIG_INT":"12345678901234567","BIG_INT_FLOATING_DECIMAL": 12345678901234567.76543210987654321}'
var p = /(?<=\"BIG_INT(?:_ARRAY_(?:SINGLE|MULTIPLE))?\":\s\[?)\d{16,}(?:,\d{16,})*/g
a = []
for (var x of s.matchAll(p)) a.push(... String(x).split(','))

console.log(a)
```